# Custom Field Labels - Field Sets VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a field set on a Visual Force Page.  I want to customize the field labels displayed to the user.

Currently, my custom contact field is birthdate, but it'd be better Date of Birth.

Here is the code:

```
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Candidate Information">
       <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.contactForm}" 
                var="c">
          <apex:inputField value="{!Contact[c]}" />
       </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

It outputs like:

Birthdate [ input field   ]

Should be:

Date of Birth  [ input field ]

Any idea how I can customize the output label?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact[c]}" label="{!IF(c.label== 'Birthdate','Date of birth',c.label)}" />
```